# powershell application - dataGridView auto updates at the end of events

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I'm working on a pre-existing powershell solution for an app that uses a scanner to import into a database, currently what I am trying to do is edit the cells of a dataGridView and validate the userInput and change the behavior of the dataGridView depending on the validity of user inputs.

This is the part of the code that does it.

```
$dataGridView_PreviewKeyDown = [System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler]`
{
    #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs]
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter')
    {
        if ($dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex -ne 0)
        {
            [int]$maxColumnIndex = $dataGridView.ColumnCount - 1;
            [int]$indexColumn = $dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            [int]$indexRow = $dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            [int]$nextColumn = $indexColumn;
            [int]$nextRow = $indexRow;
            $entryError = "";
            $global:lastColumn = $indexColumn;
            $global:lastRow = $indexRow;            
            
            $userInput = $dataGridView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;
                        
            # Si il sagit d'un numéro de série.' -WPL
            if($dataGridView.Columns[$dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name -eq "Numéro de série")
            {
                # On valide d'abord que le S/N est possible. -WPL
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($userInput))
                {
                    $entryError += "La donnée entré ne peut pas être vide.";

                }
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($entryError))
                {
                    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dataGridView.RowCount; $i++)
                    {
                        if (($userInput -eq $dataGridView.Rows[$i].Cells[$dataGridView.Columns["Numéro de série"].Index].Value) -and ($indexRow -ne 0) -and ($indexRow -ne $i))
                        {
                            $entryError += "Le numéro de série à déja été scanné.";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($entryError))
                {
                    Show-WaitForm;
                    $api = $apiToken;
                    $api.InitializeQuery("ConfigurationItem")
                    $api.AddClause("ConfigurationItem:SerialNumber", "Equal", $userInput);
                    $api.AddClause("ConfigurationItem:ID", "NotEqual", "22647");
                    $api.AddColumnUnsorted("ConfigurationItem:Name");
                    $api = $api.POSTQuery();
                    $api = [JsonHelper]::BuildHashTable($api, "ConfigurationItem");
                    $api = [JsonHelper]::BuildDataTable($api);
                    $api = $api.DefaultView.ToTable();
                    if ($api.Rows.Count -ne 0)
                    {
                        $entryError += "Le numéro de série éxiste déja dans Octopus.";
                    }
                    Close-WaitForm;
                }
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($entryError))
                {
                    if ($dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex -lt $maxColumnIndex)
                    {
                        if ($global:isLeftRight -eq $false) { $nextRow++; }
                        else { $nextColumn++; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ($global:isLeftRight -eq $true) { $nextColumn = 1; }
                        else { $nextRow++; }
                    }
                }

                # Si il y a eu des erreurs dans le traitement. -WPL
                if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($entryError))
                {
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$entryError", "Erreur", 'OK', 'Warning');
                    $global:changeEditCell = $false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $dataGridView.CurrentCell = $dataGridView[$nextColumn, $nextRow];
                    $global:changeEditCell = $true;
                }
            }
            else # Pour tout les autres colonnes, on gère normalement.
            {
                if ($global:isLeftRight -eq $true)
                {
                    if ($dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex -lt $maxColumnIndex)
                    {
                        $nextColumn++;
                        $dataGridView.CurrentCell = $dataGridView[$nextColumn, $nextRow];
                    }
                    elseif ($dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex -ge $maxColumnIndex)
                    {
                        $nextRow++;
                        $dataGridView.CurrentCell = $dataGridView[1, $nextRow];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that after correcting the current cell the events happen, the ones that I overrided appear to do what I want them to. It's just that at the end of all the events, when the application is awaiting user inputs, the dataGridView auto updates and moves the corrected cursor one row down without any way for me to intercept, because it waits for the code to be idle to make a row change.

The question is, is this an event that I need to prevent? is that auto-update unrelated with no way of preventing it? I don't want the dataGridView to simply update itself and move whenever it feels like it, thanks for any help.

I tried overriding every single events associated to the dataGridView, but alas, the auto update happens at the end regardless.

Comment: You might need to distill your code sample into a “Minimal Reproducible Example” (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is self-contained (runnable simply by cutting and pasting your code) and isolates *just* the issue you’re seeing. Your code as it stands looks like it needs a lot of scaffolding to run (create a winform, add a data grid, setup some test data, etc) which means you’re going to get a limited response as it’s not easily reproducible to investigate locally…